# shorthand for excel vba application.worksheetfunction

Tags: excel, vba

I would like a shorthand for excel `VBA` `Application.WorksheetFunction`.
It has worked well so far in the code below, but now I would like to evaluate a function, which would be similar to:

```
=IFERROR(MAX(M$2:M$64)*BINOM.DIST($W2,COUNTIF(M$2:M$64,"<"&MAX(M$2:M$64))-COUNTIF(M$2:M$64,"<"&1),0.5,FALSE),"")
```

It would be very messy to use `Application.WorksheetFunction` in front of every function I call. Please tell me how to use a shorthand.

```vb
Sub valuesCalc()
    
    Dim sumBinCenter As Double, lengthRows As Long
    sumBinCenter = 0
    lengthRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lengthRows
    
        Cells(i, "G").Value = 0.25 + sumBinCenter 'List BinCenters
        sumBinCenter = sumBinCenter + 0.5
        
    Range("H" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value + 0.25)) - Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value - 0.25))
    Range("I" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2:B" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value + 0.25)) - Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2:B" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value - 0.25))
    Range("J" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value + 0.25)) - Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value - 0.25))
    Range("K" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D2:D" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value + 0.25)) - Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D2:D" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value - 0.25))
           
    Range("M" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value + 0.25))
    Range("N" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2:B" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value + 0.25))
    Range("O" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value + 0.25))
    Range("P" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D2:D" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value + 0.25))
    
    Next i
    
    Dim intCount As Double
    intCount = -1
    
    For i = 2 To lengthRows
    
    Range("R" & i) = Cells(i, "M").Value * 100 / Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("M2:M" & lengthRows))
    Range("S" & i) = Cells(i, "N").Value * 100 / Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("N2:N" & lengthRows))
    Range("T" & i) = Cells(i, "O").Value * 100 / Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("O2:O" & lengthRows))
    Range("U" & i) = Cells(i, "P").Value * 100 / Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("P2:P" & lengthRows))
    
    Cells(i, "W").Value = 1 + intCount 'List intCounter
    intCount = intCount + 1
    
    Next i    
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A with statement would be ideal here
e.g.

```
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With
```

So in your case

```
Range("M" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2:A" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value + 0.25))
Range("N" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2:B" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value + 0.25))
Range("O" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value + 0.25))
Range("P" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D2:D" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").Value + 0.25))
```

Becomes:

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    Range("M" & i) = .CountIf(Range("A2:A" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").value + 0.25))
    Range("N" & i) = .CountIf(Range("B2:B" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").value + 0.25))
    Range("O" & i) = .CountIf(Range("C2:C" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").value + 0.25))
    Range("P" & i) = .CountIf(Range("D2:D" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").value + 0.25))
End With
```

Edit (Thanks @Wolfie):
You could also define a `WorksheetFunction` object, and use it outside of a `With` block. For instance:

```
Dim WF As WorksheetFunction
Set WF = Application.WorksheetFunction    

Range("M" & i) = WF.CountIf(Range("A2:A" & lengthRows), "<" & (Cells(i, "G").value + 0.25))
' < etc. >
```

Additional request, iferror use case:

```
Sub test()
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    MsgBox (.IfError(ActiveCell.Value, "Error"))
End With
End Sub
```

Additional request, error handling:

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 2 To lengthRows
        Err.Clear
        Range("M" & i) = maxfew * .BinomDist(Cells(i, "M").Value, numtrialsfew, 0.5, False)
        If Err > 0 Then Range("M" & i) = ""
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

Comment: thanks alot. I changed the code and it worked very well. However I tried to write the formula below and it gives me a run-time error '438: Object doesn't support this property or method. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Range("X" & i) = .IfError(.Max(Range("M2:M" & lengthRows)) * .BINOM.DIST(Cells(i, "W").Value, .CountIf(Range("M2:M" & lengthRows), "<" & .Max(Range("M2:M" & lengthRows))) - .CountIf(Range("M2:M" & lengthRows), "<" & 1), 0.5, False), "")

Comment: I guess I cannot use Bino.Dist in excel vba. I have to use BinomialPdf

Comment: This worked: Range("X" & 2) = .BinomDist(5, 10, 0.5, False)

Comment: I think the error now is using .IfError in vba. I am researching if it is possible

Comment: VBA can use Application.Worksheetfunction.Iferror or (.Iferror in this instance). I just tested it and added an example use case to the example.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am getting a run time error '1004: Unable to get the BinomDist property of the worksheet function class. The code line with the bug was Range("X" & i) = .IfError(.Max(Range("M2:M" & lengthRows)) * .BinomDist(Cells(i, "W").Value, numTrialsFeW, 0.5, False), ""). I think it has a problem with Cells(i, "W").Value, which is column with integer values.

Comment: Do you know why I am still getting run time error '1004? I have updated the line code below to clean it up and make it easier to read. The code was still evaluated on the worksheet correctly, but the error keeps coming up. Range("X" & i) = .IfError(maxFeW * .BinomDist(Cells(i, "W").Value, numTrialsFeW, 0.5, False), "")

Comment: Are you able to set a breakpoint on that line and run the macro? then you can use debug.print to test the individual elements of it to find the issue. ensure maxfew, lengthrows, i, and numtrialsfew evaluate to something expected.

Comment: Yes, I had tested each of those variables and the correct values were printed out. The code: Range("X" & i) = .IfError(maxFeW * .BinomDist(Cells(i, "W").Value, numTrialsFeW, 0.5, False), "") was evaluated correctly, but the run time error still shows up. How do I prevent the error?

Comment: You're using the W column as the success count in binom.dist, this line works correctly in testing if the value is below or equal to the total trials value, and gives 1004 error if it exceeds it. Check your column W for a value that exceeds numtrialsfew.

Comment: Yes, there are values in W that exceed numtrialsFeW. That is why I have IfError so that it give me a blank. In this example, numtrialsFeW=26. The binomial distribution was evaluated to the 26th row, which is correct and the values matched. It is doing what I want it to do. I just want to prevent the run time error from coming up each time I run the program

Comment: To avoid over-discussion i've done one last edit to the answer to show a way to handle the errors, prior to the loop we disable error breaks and test the err value to simulate iferror functionality. There may be a more elegant way but testing shows this handles the case where successes > trial count (Not my suggested approach to proceed with such data but contextually it may be suitable for you here).

Comment: Hi @Zerk, nice answer, very thorough and responsive to OP's comments. I've added a suggested edit for another shorthand without using `With`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly!! I really appreciate your help

Comment: Thank you all Zerk and Wolfie. You are all teaching me a great deal of excel vba. I have learned alot.